# Publish pbix file through Powershell or .bat file

Tags: deployment, powerbi

In our application we want to develop a deployment strategy for POWERBI. What we want to do is the developer will generate the PBIX file from its desktop and place the file in one of our predefined physical location. We will develop a script, preferably through powershell/.bat which will pick the file and publish the same.

Is there any solution through which we can achieve this feature?

Comment: The best Power BI expertise lives at http://community.powerbi.com/ You may want to try your question there

Answer (score 0):

You can use the import API for that:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/upload-a-local-pbix-file-using-the-import-api/